# Symfony2: How to override a vendor file

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, overriding, vendor

I know how to override anypart of a bundle in Symfony2. I followed [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html)

and it worked.

But what if I want to override a file in the vendor folder which is not part of a bundle.

In my specific example I need to override

```
vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/XmlDriver.php
```

Is this possible? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell the EntityManager which Metadata Driver to use:

```
<?php
$driver = new \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\XmlDriver('/path/to/mapping/files');
$em->getConfiguration()->setMetadataDriverImpl($driver);
```

Instead of the default `XmlDriver`, you use your extended version, e.g.

```
<?php
$driver = new \My\XmlDriver('/path/to/mapping/files');
$em->getConfiguration()->setMetadataDriverImpl($driver);
```

The `$em` in this snippet is the EntityManager.

See http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/metadata-drivers.html for further details on how to write and use your own Metadriver implementations.

Comment: Fortunately I did not have to try. I wanted to override it because I had some simple_xml i/o errors. These were solved so I didn't need it anymore. But thanks anyway